# How to handle Many-to-Many Relation in Django without an Intermediary Table?

Tags: django, django-models, m2m

I have inherited a weird table structure:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    account_number = models.CharField()

class Subscription(models.Model):
    account_number = models.CharField()
```

So the Customer and Subscription models are linked by their account numbers.  Each customer can have multiple subscriptions, and each subscription can have multiple customers, but there is no intermediary table; there is no "Account" table.  How do I handle this sort of thing?  If I have a Subscription queryset, how do I go about getting the corresponding Customer queryset without doing a horribly long query like

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(account_number__in=list(subscriptions.values_list('account_number', flat=True)))
```

I'm trying to avoid this because it would generate a massive query that would take a very long time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't have a m2m table, that is probably the best way to do it. However, you can optimize the query a bit to leverage Django to use subquery instead of a list of account numbers in the where statement.

```
subs = subscriptions.only('account_number').all()
customers = Customer.objects.filter(account_number__in=subs) 

# if you print out the query you should see a subquery in the query where statement
print(customers.query)
```

Comment: Thanks!  The subquery that that results in is actually the wrong one though - it selects the subscription id instead of the account id.  But the .only('account_number') bit saves some time, so thank you; I had forgotten that that existed.